# Message queues for controlling external python program via Django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, zeromq, pyzmq

I have used in a previous project used ZeroMQ to send messages between a two different python program on different servers. I now have a program that I would want to use Django as a front end for.

Doing alot of googling on message queues and python the most common thing that is coming up is Celery and RabbitMQ. But this doesn't seem like what I am looking for. Celery seems good for use produce tasks within the Django application and process them and write the result back to Django.

What I am looking for is a solution that allows me to when I create or delete a new model item to send a message to the other python program. When the other python program gets an error os simillar I want to send a message back to Django and create a new Error Model item.

Is there a good way to do this? What I could do is using different techniques for the sending and reciving from django. I could send simple UDP to my other program and post stuff back to django via HTTP API. But I think it would be nicer to have some form of messaging system that handles this and assures the messages arrives.

Comment: What blocks you from continuing using ZeroMQ?

Comment: How would integrate it into django? Wouldnt I still need a separate process for the ZMQ client, and then I would still need a way to post the data into django.

Comment: I've never used ZeroMQ but django is just python programs. How you put data in zeromq should be the same. It might happen in your views function or anywhere else. You've already mentioned posting data back to django using API and that's totally fine, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, actually I checked ZeroMQ a bit, sounds like it's pretty low level and doesn't have delivery reliability. I guess you need to use RabbitMQ, which support queuing system better. But still, you can just use it in normal python way in django without problems.

Comment: OK. Cool. RabbitMQ seems to be the thing I should use, but most info seems related to Celery.
But where would I put that code in my django project. The standard way in zeromq is to create the context and bind it to an adress. Then you need to wait a bit before you send the message since the ones that is connected might not have time to connect before the message is sent. And if you want to keep on sending messages you use a whileloop.
Is there a place in Django where I could create the context and binding at the start of the server and then just import the object and call its functions.

Comment: What kind of tasks are you looking for to send data to the queue? Periodic task? Task that triggered by web page events?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you are stuck, so I will try to cover everything.

In the project I am currently working on we are using APIs and rabbitmq to pass messages around.

We have a python, non-django process listening to a rabbitmq queue, so when Django needs to talk to it we just pump JSON formatted messages into the queue and the process picks the messages up and processes them.

You can actually use django models and other APIs with a non-django app. If that is what you want to do here is a link to start

http://blog.gabrielsaldana.org/using-django-models-in-external-python-scripts/

Our other external process needs to pass information back into Django, so we just made some API endpoints and the external process just uses HTTP POST to send data.

To do things every time a model is created or saved you want to look into Django signals.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/

If I am still missing something, you need to explain better what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very helpful. I was hoping that I could handle the recieving of rabbitmq messages in Django and then do stuff like saving data into the database. But as I understand you mean is better to just use the queue for outgoing messages and have my external process listen for the messages and for incoming messages from the external process via Django API.
Using the models from django inside python scrips seems interesting but I would want the option to separate the processes on different servers. It is not evertime I need to send a messages so signals might be a bit excessive.

Comment: Django is not a server, it is all based around request-response transactions, so continuously listening for messages is not viable with django alone. Celery integrates with django pretty well if you want to do async processing, so you could have external processes call django APIs and django offload tasks to celery. Again, I am not sure what is the actual problem you are trying to solve, so I cannot be more specific in my suggestions.

Comment: Thats fine. Your input has helped alot. :) My external python program is now a simple application that writes and reads to TCP sockets from simple GPRS modems. I. I want to control which modems that are called, and being able to stop the reading some sockets and start them again. Then I wanted to add a statistics and error logging, so interfaceing with a webapp seem like a good way to go. Have been looking into Rail to do the web app, but since i love Python I decided to learn Django instead. Other applications will interface to the web app.

Comment: Well, your external process can send statistics data to django via standard HTTP requests, since django already speaks HTTP and python standard lib includes support for making HTTP requests. As for django talking to external process there are many ways you can do it. If you are already doing plain network sockets, you can start a socket server in your external process and talk to it via sockets. You can use HTTP server from python standard lib and have django talk HTTP as well. You can use a queue server like rabbitmq if you expect to send a lot of messages and the order is important to you.